# How to loop through two GridViews to find the same values? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2015

I have two GridViews on my page - `grvBookCategories` shows categories of one particular book and `grvCategories` contains all possible categories for library. `grvBookCategories` is shown when page loads and `grvCategories` is fired on button click. There is checkbox `cbxGrvCategories` in ItemTemplate of `grvCategories`.

Question is - how to loop through those two GridViews to find the same values in both of them (both contain column with category name)? If there is a match - corresponding checkbox should be checked. For example - if there are 3 rows in `grvBookCategories` then 3 checkboxes should be also checked in `grvCategories`.

I've tried to do that using grvCategories_RowDataBound event and foreach loops but results are not exactly correct. The problem is when there is a match in the last  `grvCategories` row. In such case checkbox in that row in never checked, for all other rows results are fine.

```
protected void grvCategories_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    string rowcValue = "";
    string rowbcValue = "";
    CheckBox cbx = new CheckBox();
    foreach (GridViewRow rowc in grvCategories.Rows)
    {
      if (rowc.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        rowcValue = rowc.Cells[2].Text;
        cbx = (CheckBox)rowc.Cells[3].FindControl("cbxGrvCategories");
        foreach (GridViewRow rowbc in grvBookCategories.Rows)
        {
          if (rowbc.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          {
            rowbcValue = rowbc.Cells[1].Text;
            if (rowcValue.Equals(rowbcValue))
            {
              cbx.Checked = true;
              break;
            }
            else
            {
              cbx.Checked = false;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow row1 in G1.Rows)
        { if (row1.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
             string gv1Value = row1.Cells[0].Text;
                //iterate second gridview  
                foreach (GridViewRow row2 in G2.Rows)
                {
                    if (row2.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        string gv2Value = row2.Cells[0].Text;
                        //do comparison here  
                        if (gv1Value.Equals(gv2Value))
                        {
                        }}}}}

Comment: Searching fields in a GridView like this will only work with `BoundField` columns. Not `TemplateField` and `AutoGenerated` Columns. Better to do a search on the source data.

Comment: @viveknuna  Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me

Comment: @VDWWD Data from database are in BoundField, buttons are placed in TemplateField, AutoGenerateColumns is false. So can't it be done somehow?

Comment: If it are boundfields then it can be done. It looks like you are on the right track with the code in `grvCategories_RowDataBound`. What exactly are those "totally wrong results"? What are they and what is expected? And did you bind the data in`grvCategories` before `grvBookCategories`? Otherwise the search will always be false.

Comment: Before `grvCategories_RowDataBound` there is `button_Click` event, where data from database were bound. So, data in GrivView are correct, only buttons are not shown in proper way.

Comment: For instance - `grvBookCategories` has 3 rows. Corresponding rows from `grvCategories` are: 1,6 and 10 (there are 11 rows total), so `btnGrvCategoriesRemove` should be visible only in that rows. Instead, it is shown only in the last row, in the first row none of the buttons is visible and the rest remaining rows show `btnGrvCategoriesAdd`.

Comment: My code changed and that's why I've just edited the post, so the conversation above is not actual anymore. Please, help me with actual code.

Comment: If you use only the tiniest bit of architecture in your code life becomes so much easier. A Gridview is only a control to _show_ the data. You bind it to some datastructure, at least something like a DataTable. And that is where you go look for duplicates and other stuff.

Comment: Data from DataSet are shown correctly in BoundFields of both GridViews.